# How to make Mediawiki require alphanumeric passwords?

Tags: mediawiki

How can I force new user registrations in mediawiki to use alphanumeric passwords?

At the moment they only need letters.

There is not way to edit LocalSettings.php, so I would have to modify the base files, but the question is which one?

Comment: Why? This is a security nightmare...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest, unless you want to create your own hook to verify the password, is probably to use the [SecurePasswords extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SecurePasswords) (or, possibly, the [SafeCreate extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SafeCreate)) that will allow you to configure a number of things regarding required complexity of the passwords.

If you *really* want to create your own hook, the hook you want to create is an [isValidPassword hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/isValidPassword).